# How to write a test case method having System.exit() using Junit 5?

Tags: junit5, system.exit

Scenario: Below negative scenario to be tested during Integration test. currently the test case getting failed due exit and not reaching to the test method.

example :

```
private void method1(int a){
try{
  if(a == 0){
    throw exception();
  }else{
     ---
  }
 }catch(exceptionclass e){
    System.exit(1);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Sound like a bad smell to me that calling a method on a object can cause JVM to exist. Normally it should be done in the main method.

So I would refactor your codes such that your testing object will throw a kind of `Exception` to indicate that some kind of fatal error happens such that the main method can catch it and terminate the JVM.

Then you can simply test that if it will throw this `Exception` from your test case.

Comment: actually i must return exit code to shell script to handle further

Comment: let the main method to return it but not return it by the an object

Comment: Sorry still I am not clear, calling System.exit(1) from method level or from main method, how it is different? either way Integration test case will fail right?